# How to navigate to docker volumes folders on the host machine

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I'm trying to find out where VOLUME "**/shared**" is mapped to (Mac) and how to navigate to it on the host machine

I run

> docker run -it --volume /shared ubuntu:latest /bin/bash

Then I inspect where it's mapped to:

> docker inspect d2e17f3d3bb4

And see the excerpt from the config:

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "volume",
        "Name": "fb7ace0b18153bdad1744f0ac18eadc3775929dd5f448ebb228e7130f86c1a19",
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/fb7ace0b18153bdad1744f0ac18eadc3775929dd5f448ebb228e7130f86c1a19/_data",
        "Destination": "/shared",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": ""
    }
```

And there is not such folder on the host machine:

> /var/lib/docker/volumes/fb7ace0b18153bdad1744f0ac18eadc3775929dd5f448ebb228e7130f86c1a19/_data

Not even **/var/lib/docker/volumes**

/var/lib/docker doesn't exist

**Edited:**

Thanks to @BMitch

The answer is

1. **Docker VM is located at**

> ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2

2. **Navigate to the VM**

> screen
>   ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty

3. Within the tty one can navigate to **/var/lib/docker** and docker volumes

Comment: `$ cd /var/lib/docker && sudo ls`, Dosn't it still show `volumes` dir?

Comment: What is `$DOCKER_HOST` set to, what type of docker install (Linux, Mac, Windows), and are you root?

Comment: cd: /var/lib/docker: No such file or directory

Comment: $DOCKER_HOST is empty, 
I run it on Mac

Comment: @BMitch Thank you a lot about a link, the question is the same but the output not quite the same, the answer in the link didn't include how one can navigate to the specified folders

Comment: Please update your question to show how you're facing a problem not answered in the duplicate question and tag me so I can submit to have this reopened. Thanks.

Comment: @BMitch Please, see the answer